# Count how much a value exists in object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a object with quite some data and its almost unreadable so I want to count how much a specific value exists in that object.

I know how to check if it does exist this way:

```
if (in_array("value", $array)) {
    echo "Match found";
} else {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

But I want how often the match is found.

I was thinking about this but that didn't work.

```
echo count(in_array('133171'), $object->List);
```

How is it possible to do this in PHP?

EDIT: this is how the first part of the object looks like with its first 3 values:

```
stdClass Object ( [errorcode] => 1000 [message] => Ok, stand data follows [List] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [naam] => value1 1 [TeamID] => value2 [ClubNummer] => value3
```

Comment: Is it an array or an object?

Comment: I need it working for a object

Comment: stdClass Object ( [errorcode] => 1000 [message] => Ok, stand data follows [List] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [naam] => Naam

---------This is the beginning of the object with the first value

Comment: Please add an example of how part of the object looks like in your question

Comment: [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: We need to see a more complete example of your array and what result you expect exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use this algorithm :

```
$nb = 0;
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    if ($entry == "value")
        $nb++;
}
```

or with `array_walk` :

```
$tab = array('one' => "Dog", 'two' => 'Cat', 'three' => "Dog");

$nbDogs = 0;
$searched = "Dog";
array_walk($tab,
           function ($value, $key) use (&$nbDogs, $searched) {
               if ($value == $searched)
                   $nbDogs++;
            });

echo "nbDogs = $nbDogs\n";
```

Comment: thanks the first code with the algorithm worked for me

Comment: You can use `use` on the anonymous function instead of `global`, btw. I find it much neater. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-195

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know 'use', I patched the answer.